# Why the frequency response is similar for different inputs?

Tags: fft

I am new to DSP, learning some stuff, and looking for some advice from experts here. I am using the CMSIS DSP lib to get the frequency response of a dummy input signal that's a combination of 10 Hz + 30 Hz. Below is the code I am using.

```
#include "arm_math.h"
#include "arm_const_structs.h"

/* std */
#include <stdio.h>

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CMSIS DSP related
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
float32_t input[2048] = { // combination of 10 Hz and 30 Hz signals

};

float32_t output[2048] = {0};
uint32_t fftSize = 1024;    // fft size
uint32_t ifftFlag = false;  // forward fft i.e. time--->frequency 
uint32_t doBitReverse = true; // enable bit reversal

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Main
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

int main(void)
{
    ...
    for(uint16_t i = 0 ; i < fftSize ; i = i+2){
        //input[i] = 0.000000000000000;
    }
    
    INV_MSG(INV_MSG_LEVEL_INFO, "[Input]===>");
    for(uint16_t i = 0, j = 1 ; i < fftSize ; i++, j++){
        INV_MSG(INV_MSG_LEVEL_INFO, "%hu ,%f\r", j,  input[i]);
        inv_delay_ms(1);
    }
    
    arm_cfft_f32(&arm_cfft_sR_f32_len512, input, ifftFlag, doBitReverse); //  Process the data through the CFFT/CIFFT module
    arm_cmplx_mag_f32(input, output, fftSize / 2); // Process the data through the Complex Magnitude Module for calculating the magnitude at each bin 
    
    INV_MSG(INV_MSG_LEVEL_INFO, "================");
    INV_MSG(INV_MSG_LEVEL_INFO, "[Magnitude]===>");
    INV_MSG(INV_MSG_LEVEL_INFO, "================");
    for(uint16_t i = 0 ; i < fftSize / 2 ; i++){
        INV_MSG(INV_MSG_LEVEL_INFO, "%f", output[i]);
        inv_delay_ms(1);
    }
    
    while(1);
}
```

I have two cases here (more details, waveforms, etc shown in the attached spreadsheet/below images). Case-1 shows the response for input samples with real and img interleaved with img values being 0. The same goes for Case-2 except that this time the input samples only have real values.

**CASE-1:**
[image: Case-1]

**CASE-2:**
[image: Case-2]
I have a few questions based on the above results.

**Question 1**: Which is the right way to input data Case-1 or Case-2?

**Question 2**: Why the response for both Case-1 and Case-2 are identical while the inputs are populated differently as described above?

**Question 3**: We should be seeing peaks at 10 Hz and 30 Hz, but in the plot, we can see it's slightly shifted - any insights on why this may have happened and how to get better results?

Comment: If you need the input samples/array, I am happy to share them with you. I wasn't able to add that to the code since it's a massive array and had already exceeded my word limit.

Comment: For Your 3rd question, note that the dft is samples of the dtft, in your case the dtft is not sampled at it's peak, thus you may think it has been shifted, but its not . As for your second question, as I understand, case 1 input is the same as the case 2 but with missing half of the data ans zero padded, padding your input with zeros only makes your spectrum resolution diferent (i.e sampling the dtft with diferent resolution)

Comment: @RanGreidi, sorry I don't understand your answer to the 3rd question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yea I will elaborate later today/tomoroow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: Which is the right way to input data Case-1 or Case-2?

If you are using  `arm_cfft_f32` case 1 is correct, the imaginary and real components should be interleaved. Case 2 is correct for arm_rfft_f32.

Question 2: Why the response for both Case-1 and Case-2 are identical while the inputs are populated differently as described above?

The outputs are not identical, note the amplitudes of your FFT are different. For the same data, you should have the exact same output.

Question 3: We should be seeing peaks at 10 Hz and 30 Hz, but in the plot, we can see it's slightly shifted - any insights on why this may have happened and how to get better results?

Have you calculated the X axis positions correctly?

Comment: For Q3, I had offset by mistake while plotting. Cheers!